# \fancyfoot does not work in a chapter and macros

Tags: fonts, macros, header-footer, footnotes, page-numbering

I used a template to write a document where I found a Macro for the chapter form. 
The problem is how can I get the \fancyfoot that I want in the chapter page. 
Exemple :

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat = empty,position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage[dvips,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[Style]{fncychap}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{~-}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
%\setcellgapes{1pt}
%\makegapedcells
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand{\seyesDefault}{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\linespread{1.5}
\date{}
\sloppy

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@alph\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%style%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill
\kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%\vspace*{50\p@}%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
%{\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font \thickhrulefill\quad
{\parindent \z@ \centering \thickhrulefill\quad
\scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter \quad \thickhrulefill
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\interlinepenalty\@M \hrule
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\par
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\hrule
%\vskip 40\p@
\vskip 100\p@ }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
%\vspace*{50\p@}%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
%{\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font \thickhrulefill
{\parindent \z@ \centering \thickhrulefill
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\interlinepenalty\@M \hrule
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\par
\vspace*{10\p@}%
\hrule
%\vskip 40\p@
\vskip 100\p@ }}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{- \thepage\ -}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{Thèse de Doctorat}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{Name of }}

\begin{document}

\input{Abstract.tex}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first page of a chapter uses the `plain` page style, so you have to redefine it:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{- \thepage\ -}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{Thèse de Doctorat}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{Name of }}
}%
```

Unrelated: you should load `hyperref` as the last package, with very few exceptions. Also, since version 3.9, the language options for `babel` should be loaded with the \ documentclass, so that all language-dependent packages be aware of the main language of your document.

Last point: if you redefine your sectional layouts with personal macros, there's no point to load `titlesec`.